# How to handle searches for very common keywords

Tags: coldfusion, solr, coldfusion-9

I want to be able to return useful records if a user searches for a keyword that is very, very common in a solr index. For example `education`.

In this case, close to 99% of the records would have that word in it. So searches for this word or similar take a long time.

This is for **solr on ColdFusion** but I'm open to solutions which are isolated to just solr.

Right now I'm thinking of coming up with a list of stopwords and preventing those searches from taking place altogether.

Comment: I assume searches are taking a long time because CFSEARCH is trying to grab all of the results, rather than the top (say) 100 results? You can avoid this by not using CFSEARCH and using Solr's web service instead. See http://www.thefaberfamily.org/search-smith/coldfusion-solr-tutorial/ for more information.

Comment: Not sure how I forgot this, but the CFSEARCH tag does have a `maxrows` attribute as well -- so if the length of time the search takes is the issue then that should solve it.

Comment: do people really search on "education"? If you were indexing resumes and all/most resumes contained the word "education", "experience", or "objective" I would make them noise words.

Comment: These are end users. Of course they search for education, even though this is a digital library containing documents exclusively about education.

Comment: @DavidFaber, maybe post this as an answer with a little elaboration so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If searches are taking a long time, it could be because you are not limiting the number of results that are returned. The `<cfsearch>` tag has a `maxrows` attribute, as well as a `startrow` attribute, that you could use to limit or paginate the data. Alternately, you could call Solr's web service directly through a `<cfhttp>` call:

```
<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_name>/select/?q=<searchterm>&fl=*,score&rows=100&wt=json" />
```

Solr will return 10 rows by default; you can change this with the `rows` parameter. You can use the `start` parameter as well (note that Solr starts counting with 0 instead of 1). I believe this solution is more flexible, especially if you're using CF 9, as it allows you to paginate while sorting on a field other than score.

You can find more detail here:
http://www.thefaberfamily.org/search-smith/coldfusion-solr-tutorial/

Comment: Okay, right now I am combining the search results with a query using a query-of-queries so I will have to figure out some way to make this work better.

Comment: You can do something similar using the above by creating a new query with `queryNew()` and populating it with the resulting struct from deserializing the JSON results.

Comment: The main issue is if I want to sort by, say, popularity which is a field from the other query, and I only pull in the first x records, when I sort by popularity I might not get the most popular records if I cut off the search results.

Comment: You can specify the sort in your Solr query as long as it is a field that is indexed. So if you're going with the basic CF Solr collection (without modifying `schema.xml` for example), you can store the popularity in custom1, custom2, etc. when indexing the collection.

Comment: Example: `<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_name>/select/?q=<searchterm>&fl=*,score&rows=100&sort=popularity&wt=json" />` One of the great things about querying Solr this way instead of through CFSEARCH (at least until CF 10) is that you can paginate the results regardless of the field on which you're sorting. In CF 9 and below, CFSEARCH sorts on score so you have to get *all* of the results if you want to sort on something else.

Comment: As I understand it, only 4 fields are available in CF9. I already have one holding the real primary key of the record (since the "key" field for files will be holding the file name), then another for storing its source, and another storing author information. Unfortunately I want to be able to sort by more than 4 fields, and I only have one custom field left! So I think I may have to look into manually indexing the papers as well...

Comment: It is possible to cram a bunch of fields into one of the custom_n fields using a delimiter, but I would only advise doing that if you don't plan on sorting on those fields. You also have the `title` field available by default.

Comment: I'm indexing documents (PDFs, etc.) with bad metadata, and unfortunately even if you specify a value for the title field in `cfindex` it just populates it with what it pulls from the document. So I have to store the title in a custom field.

Comment: Gotcha. You might have to crack open schema.xml, add custom fields, and use the Solr API (rather than CFINDEX) to index then. It is well worth it once you get it all figured out. Let me know if I can be of any assistance.

Comment: The real headache is re-indexing 30k documents, plus adding in the code to index the binary docs (PDFs).

Answer (score 0):

If the user searches on just one term that is exceedingly common then you need to limit your results and advise the user that there were too many matches.

In the more general case, you want to perform a two-pass (at least) approach. Take your search terms and perform a lookup to determine their 'common-ness'. You want to filter based on least common terms first, and more common terms last.

For example, user searches `serendipitous education`. You identify that you have 11 matches for `serendipitous`, and 900000 matches for `education`. Thus you apply the `serendipitous` filter first, resulting in 11 matches. Then apply the `education` filter, resulting in 7 matches.

The key to fast searching is indexing and precomputed statistics. If you have statistics like this on hand you can dynamic create an optimised approach.